# How to merge all data frames in the global environment respectively?

Tags: r

I've got a bunch of dataframes and want to merge all of them. But the point here is it should be sorted from master1 to master11 and the number of df isn't constant. The problem starts after master10 and so on.

```
DF_obj <- lapply(ls(pattern = ".*master"), get)
df <- DF_obj %>% reduce(left_join, by = "commonvar")
```

The code below is an example to explain it.

```
master1 <- data.frame(x = LETTERS[1:10], y1 = sample(1:100,10))
master2 <- data.frame(x = LETTERS[1:10], y2 = sample(1:100,10))
master10 <- data.frame(x = LETTERS[1:10], y3 = sample(1:100,10))
DF_obj <- lapply(ls(pattern = ".*master"), get)
library(dplyr);library(purrr)
gendf <- DF_obj %>% reduce(left_join, by = "x")
```

How to overcome this problem? Thanks.

Comment: You can use gtools::mixedsort to sort the names.

Comment: The problem is solved. `select(x, sort(names(.)))`

Comment: sort would sort master10 before master2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to replace `x` with your actual `id` column in the data to eliminate warning/error messages.

You may do either of two

base R

````r
``` r
master1 <- data.frame(x = LETTERS[1:10], y1 = sample(1:100,10))
master2 <- data.frame(x = LETTERS[1:10], y2 = sample(1:100,10))
master10 <- data.frame(x = LETTERS[1:10], y3 = sample(1:100,10))
DF_obj <- lapply(ls(pattern = ".*master"), get)

gendf <- Reduce(function(.x, .y) merge(.x, .y, by = 'x'), x = DF_obj[-1], init = DF_obj[1]) 
  
gendf[, order(names(gendf))]
#>    x y1 y2  y3
#> 1  A 37 86  61
#> 2  B  3 23  89
#> 3  C 69 46  95
#> 4  D 16  9  54
#> 5  E 62 85  52
#> 6  F 19  5  35
#> 7  G 55 28  90
#> 8  H 40 52   5
#> 9  I  7 48 100
#> 10 J 48 16   9
````

---

`tidyverse`

```r
master1 <- data.frame(x = LETTERS[1:10], y1 = sample(1:100,10))
master2 <- data.frame(x = LETTERS[1:10], y2 = sample(1:100,10))
master10 <- data.frame(x = LETTERS[1:10], y3 = sample(1:100,10))
DF_obj <- lapply(ls(pattern = ".*master"), get)

library(tidyverse)
purrr::reduce(DF_obj[-1], .init = DF_obj[1], ~ .x %>% as.data.frame() %>% left_join(.y, by = 'x'))
#>    x y1  y3 y2
#> 1  A 77  87 93
#> 2  B 10  18 74
#> 3  C  2  89 64
#> 4  D 89  98  5
#> 5  E 13  99 21
#> 6  F 74  25  4
#> 7  G 87   4 22
#> 8  H 62  27 17
#> 9  I 14  10 99
#> 10 J 21 100 78
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

**Since the random seed has not been fixed, the results are different in two reprexes.**

Comment: Thanks for your answer but the column names should be sorted so what I want is y1, y2, and y3 based on master1, master2, master10.

Comment: @nerdakgul That isn't is a difficult task.  See edited answer (first part) :)

Comment: Writing so much code and get stuck on the smallest thing :) Thank you.

Comment: @nerdakgul, Glad to have been of help.  If your main problem was to sort the column according to colnames, perhaps your question title conveyed it differently. :)

Comment: I already regretted posting but won't delete it :)